# Flutter : serState() or markNeedBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, builder, consumer

- I have a widget which used to select a date, at beginning it's with 'no date chosen', and the widget in a column below it depends on it [which mean its show a list of timeSlots of Data if I selected a date]
- **But I got a setState called during build error, and This ReservationSlotWidget  can not be marked as needing to build because the Framework is already in the process of building widgets**
- This is the selectDate widget

```
 child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.date_range,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        _formatted == null
                        ? 'No date chosen'
                        : _formatted,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: ()=>_selectReservationDate(context),
                      child: Text(
                      'choose Date',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              if(_selectedDate != null)
              Divider(
                color: parseColor('#2A2E43'),
                thickness: 2.0,
              ),
              if(_selectedDate != null)
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.alarm,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Text('$_numberOfSeats Available Time Slots',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ))
                ],
              ),
```

- this is a listview items which appeared depend on the date I chose.

```
              if(_formatted != null)
         
  Expanded(
                  child: Consumer<SlotProvider>(
                    builder: (ctx, slotProvider, _)=>
                     ListView.builder(
                itemCount: slotProvider.slots.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    setState(() {
                      _numberOfSeats = slotProvider.slots[index].seats;
                    });
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if(_isInit){
                          _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
                          }
                           _expandedIndex = index;
                          _isInit = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: _expandedIndex == index
                                  ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                                  : parseColor('#2A2E43'),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                          child: SlotsWidget(
                            fromTime: slotProvider.slots[index].fromTime.toString(),
                            toTime:slotProvider.slots[index].toTime.toString(),
                            seats:slotProvider.slots[index].seats,
                          ))
                          );
                          }
              ),
                  )
              ),
```

Comment: Calling `setState((){})` in the `itemBuilder` of your `ListView` is the reason for the error.

Comment: but a number of seats changed depends on date and the index of the timeSlot i choose [ _numberOfSeats = slotProvider.slots[index].seats;]

Answer (score 0):

the comment of [@void](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13452640/void) is right and you can avoid the repeated setState with if block;

```
if (_numberOfSeats != slotProvider.slots[index].seats)
   setState(() {
      _numberOfSeats = slotProvider.slots[index].seats;
   });
```